# Issue on my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello all i have a search activity into my app that works good if i try to search an item by tiping a text keyword but if i try to search an item that also contain a number app crash. For example if i try to search the text "home" search works good but if i search "home 3" app crash. The error is : exception-illegal-character-in-query-at-index I want that the search works good also by typing a text or a text + number exc.. 
Thank you

IMPORTANT : 
the search activity call an encoded url, "ADSEARCH_URL"

```
public static final String ADSEARCH_URL="https://gjeme.com/apps/menjehere/index.php?action=searchAd&categoryId=%s&adcity=%s&q=%s";
```

This is the search activity :

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ListView lsv;
String categoryId,keyword,city;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
List<CatAdd> catAddList;
CateAdDisplayAdapter adapter;
Typeface typeface;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_search);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle("Browse Ads");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
    getActionBarTextView();

    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GandhiSerif-    Bold.otf");
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    lsv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    catAddList = new ArrayList<CatAdd>();

    categoryId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("categoryId", "0");
    keyword    = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyword","keyword");
    city       = getIntent().getExtras().getString("city","city");

    new SearchList().execute();

    lsv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),             BrowseAdsDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("adId",     String.valueOf(catAddList.get(arg2).getAddid()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id==android.R.id.home)
    {
    onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}
private TextView getActionBarTextView() {
    TextView titleTextView = null;

    try {
    Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    titleTextView = (TextView)f.get(toolbar);
    titleTextView.setTypeface(typeface);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return titleTextView;
}

class SearchList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    String jsonStr = null;
    CustomProgressDialog cd = new CustomProgressDialog();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    cd.showdialog(SearchActivity.this, "Loading...");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    jsonStr =       sh.makeServiceCall(String.format(Constants.ADSEARCH_URL,categoryId,city,keyword)    , ServiceHandler.GET);
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Constants.TAG);
            for (int i = contacts.length()-1; i > -1; i--) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String adId = c.getString(Constants.CAT_ADID);
                String adTitle = c.getString(Constants.CAT_ADTITLE);
                String adDes = c.getString(Constants.CAT_ADDES);
                String adCreatedAt = c.getString("adCreatedAt");
                String adcity= c.getString(Constants.CAT_CITY);
                String adPrise= c.getString(Constants.CAT_PRICE);

                JSONArray arrImages=c.getJSONArray("images");
                ArrayList<String> imgArray=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int j=0;j<arrImages.length();j++)
                {
                    JSONObject imgObj=arrImages.getJSONObject(j);
                    if(imgObj.has("imageName"))
                    {
                        imgArray.add(imgObj.getString("imageName"));
                    }

                }
                CatAdd v=new CatAdd();
                v.setAddid(Integer.parseInt(adId));
                v.setAdTitle(adTitle);
                v.setAdDesc(adDes);
                v.setAdCreatedAt(adCreatedAt);
                v.setAdPrice(adPrise);
                v.setImglist(imgArray);
                v.setAdCity(adcity);
                catAddList.add(v);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        cd.dismissdialog();
        adapter = new CateAdDisplayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),             catAddList);
        lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the xml definition of the textview.

Comment: the problem is that when he call the url, the url not recognize the other character, named as ''illegal''. But i not know how to make a goddo encoded url call what i'm going to modify on my ADSEARCH_URL for obtaining a good response of a text with or not number

Comment: The xml contain only the listview

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any problem with alpha-numeric characters here, but the **SPACE** is created one, while you are adding the text to URL. 
Replace `space(es)` of searched keyword with `%20` and hopefully you will find it fine.

Comment: you mean to add this https://gjeme.com/apps/menjehere/index.php?action=searchAd&categoryId=%s&adcity=%s&q=%s%20

Comment: No, I meant make sure that the URL doesn't have any space character. Like  ` https://gjeme.com/apps/menjehere/index.php?action=searchAd 3&categoryId=%s&adcity=%s&q=%s%20 ` here we have space between searchAd & 3, which will throw Illegal exception. so all you have to do replace this space character with ` %20 `